# Check web application availability via batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible via batch to continuously check the availability of a downed web app which is being started (eg 192.168.1.4:8080) and print a message when the application is up.

Comment: with the latest builds of windows 10 there's curl installed by default: https://ss64.com/nt/curl.html  - you can use it for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Installing curl for windows helped to avoid going through the hectic Power Shell commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what he saied @npocmaka in his comment you can use `curl`

```bat
@echo off
Mode 60,3
Title Check URL
Set "URL=https://www.stackoverflow.com"

:Check_URL
Cls
Curl -I -s "%URL%" | find /I "200">nul 2>&1 && (
    color 0A
    echo(
    echo(      "%URL%" ==^> is OK
 ) || (
    color 0C
    echo(
    echo(      "%URL%" ==^> Not OK
)

Timeout /T 10 /NoBreak>nul
Goto Check_URL
```